# C++ program gives different results in Debug and Release mode

Tags: c++

I'm doing some algorithmic exercises and I encountered a strange problem. I wrote the code below to solve this problem http://main.edu.pl/en/archive/oi/21/pta. I tested it and it looks like it works fine in Debug mode, but as soon as I switch to Release (or submit it to the site) it gives wrong answers to some tests.

Eg for 9e.in (I uploaded this test here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ki4vfk2p5140xwo/pta9e.in?dl=0) the answer I get from Debug build is correct:

```
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
```

However, in Release (and after submitting to the site) I get:

```
543
530
530
530
530
530
543
530
530
530
543
530
530
543
530
530
530
543
530
530
543
530
530
530
530
```

I have no idea what can be causing this problem :/ This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int numOfTrees = 0;
int* trees = NULL;

int numOfBirds = 0;

int computeBird(int birdStamina)
{
    int tired = 0;

    int position = 0;
    int lastTree = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (position >= numOfTrees - 1)
        {
            return tired;
        }

        lastTree = trees[position];

        int furthestGoodTree = -1;

        int tallestTreePos = position + birdStamina;
        if (tallestTreePos > numOfTrees - 1)
        {
            tallestTreePos = numOfTrees - 1;
        }

        int tallestTreeSize = trees[tallestTreePos];

        for (int n = 1; n <= birdStamina; ++n)
        {
            int pos = position + n;

            if (pos >= numOfTrees)
                break;

            if (trees[pos] < lastTree)
            {
                if (trees[pos] >= trees[furthestGoodTree])
                {
                    furthestGoodTree = pos;
                }
            }

            if (trees[pos] >= tallestTreeSize)
            {
                tallestTreeSize = trees[pos];
                tallestTreePos = pos;
            }
        }

        if (furthestGoodTree != -1)
        {
            position = furthestGoodTree;
        }
        else
        {
            position = tallestTreePos;
            tired++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &numOfTrees);

    trees = new int[numOfTrees + 2];

    int val = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < numOfTrees; ++n)
    {
        scanf("%d", &val);
        trees[n] = val;
    }

    scanf("%d", &numOfBirds);

    int* cache = new int[numOfTrees + 2];

    for (int n = 0; n < numOfTrees; ++n)
    {
        cache[n] = -1;
    }

    int results[30];

    int birdStamina = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < numOfBirds; ++n)
    {
        scanf("%d", &birdStamina);

        if (cache[birdStamina] != -1)
        {
            results[n] = cache[birdStamina];
        }
        else
        {
            int result = computeBird(birdStamina);

            cache[birdStamina] = result;
            results[n] = result;
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < numOfBirds; ++n)
    {
        printf("%d\n", results[n]);
    }

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the program down to a few lines that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &birdStamina); if (cache[birdStamina] != -1)` - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: I dont know which lines are causing the problem thats why I ask

Comment: scanf("%d", &birdStamina); if (cache[birdStamina] != -1) this is remembering previous answers so it won't compute the same result twice

Comment: Makes no sense to me. Why would user input be within your cache boundaries?

Comment: birdStamina is less than numOfTrees so it will be within the input boundaries

Comment: @piotrek you start by simplifying the program line by line until the problem goes away. When it does, take a step back. If that helped you find the problem, then you don't need to come here. Otherwise, keep simplifying until only a [mcve] exists. If you still can't figure it out, then you can post the mcve here and ask for help.

Comment: In general, the basis of the issue is an uninitialized variable.  Many debuggers will initialize memory to a know value.  Release mode does not.

Comment: I recommend walking through your program with a debugger and *watching* the values of the variables.

Comment: I am concerned about the arrays (cache and trees) that are 2 items larger than the size initialized.

Comment: Next time I will know that there is never a warrning when accessing incorrect array index. So thank you guys, my solution got 100/100 points ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code really ought to have the assert I added

```
       if (trees[pos] < lastTree)
        {
            assert( furthestGoodTree >= 0 );
            if (trees[pos] >= trees[furthestGoodTree])
            {
                furthestGoodTree = pos;
            }
        }
```

So far as I can tell, that condition would be data dependent, not forced by other code and certainly not forced by any local code.

When you rely on some condition being true and it is not locally obvious why it should be true, you should have an `assert` so debug runs will notice incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Well thats was the problem. If the furthestGoodTree was -1 it accessed the array at position -1 what is obviously incorrect. It's surprising it worked well in Debug mode :) Thanks! (not enough reputation to upvote but will mark as correct answer)

Comment: Please understand the reason I phrased my answer that way:  you should have such an assert in such a case.  I suspected that was the bug, but fixing that bug is not the important part of the answer.  Fixing the coding style is more important.  Most indexes you used have locally obvious reasons (such as run time checks) why they are in range.  When indexes have no locally obvious reason to be in range, even if some distant code makes them reliably correct, you should have an appropriate `assert`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what input data do you enter, but it seems to me you are out of arrays boundaries. In example, you allocate **cache** as array of **numOfTrees**, but later read it by index **numOfBirds**. I assume the release and debug versions have different memory allocations, and thus your out-of-boundary read gives you different results.

Comment: Yeah, I was accessing array of trees using incorrect index -1 and it gave me corrupted results. In debug mode it returned 0 but in release it breaks.

Comment: Undefined behavior is **undefined**: when `furthestGoodTree==-1`, `trees[pos] >= trees[furthestGoodTree]` is undefined.  So in theory, the possible results are not limited to `true` or `false`.  But in practice, in this particular case, the result is just `true` or `false`, but apparently `true` in debug and `false` in release.  Since `true` gave the behavior you really wanted, the debug build seemed to work.  Next time, such behavior should not be a surprise.

Comment: I don't know why each answer got a downvote (my answer also got an upvote balancing the downvote).  The basic idea of an array access out of range is the same in both answers and was the obvious suspect from the original question. For my answer, I chose the array access that looked less sound.  dmi chose a different array access, but another one that a careful programmer would consider unsound (worth at least an assert and maybe a run time check).  In hindsight, dmi didn't guess the right array access.  But it was a perfectly good answer based on available info.